# How to change UICollectionView height

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` that I would like set the height to a fixed amount, no matter the content displayed. Right now if there are very few cells displayed, scrolling is disabled. However I would like the height to be a certain amount and thus scrolling to be always enabled, even if there is no content. How would I do this?

I have tried to override the `collectionViewContentSize` method in flow layout class but it leads to bad access errors. i.e.

```
- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize {
    return CGSizeMake(320, 500);    
}
```

Comment: `collectionViewContentSize` is a method of the `UICollectionViewLayout` class so you'll need to override it there (in a subclass); not in `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

Comment: Oh, right. Turns out the errors were due to another issue. Overriding collectionViewContentSize in the flow layout seemed to work as well (but now I know it's a method of ViewLayout, not FlowLayout). Thanks.